# Wiremock Capture path param and return in the response body

Tags: wiremock

I am trying to create dynamic mocks using WireMock. I have a situation where if I specify URL like :

```
http://localhost:8089/api/account/abc@abc.com
```

then I should receive response like:

```
{ 
  "account" : "abc@abc.com" 
}
```

In brief, the path param is returned in the response body. I am able to make the request URL generic by using `urlPathPattern` set to `/api/account/([a-z]*)` however, I am not sure how should I capture `abc@abc.com` and return this in the response using regular expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In WireMock the regular expressions can be used to recognize the email format in the [Request Matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/). For the purpose of this example I used a very crude example. Your production implementation may require a more robust approach.

This request:

```
http://localhost:8181/api/account/someone@somewhere.net
```

Is matched by this rule:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "urlPathPattern": "/api/account/([a-z]*@[a-z]*.[a-z]*)"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
            "account": "{{request.path.[2]}}"
        },
        "transformers": ["response-template"],
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

And returns this response:

```
{
  "account": "someone@somewhere.net"
}
```

It makes use of a [Response Template](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/) processing functionality in WireMock. The [Request Model variables](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#the-request-model) [`{{request.path.[2]}}`] can be used to obtain sections from the request.

Comment: Thanks a lot @A. Kootstra for responding to my question. The solution outlined by yourself has worked for me and I am now building more complex tests. Awesome, Cheers mate !!!

Comment: Nice answer! This snippet may also save some search time: `WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options().<other options>.extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true)))`

Answer (score 1):

The same can be done using [WireMock.Net - Response-Templating](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net/wiki/Response-Templating)

The rule looks like:

```
{
    "Request": {
        "Path": {
            "Matchers": [
                {
                    "Name": "RegexMatcher",
                    "Pattern": "^/api/account/([a-z]*@[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Methods": [
            "get"
        ]
    },
    "Response": {
        "StatusCode": 200,
        "BodyAsJson": {
            "account": "{{request.PathSegments.[2]}}"
        },
        "UseTransformer": true,
        "Headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```